# Row of numbers inside boxes with arrow crossing from one box to another with TikZ PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a graphic exactly like on this image:

[image: example]

After research, it seems like using TikZ PGF with a matrix is the ideal choise. Unfortunately, I couldn't come up with the code (I'm totally new to Latex). I'd be very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! A matrix would be an excellent choice but perhaps the following is even simpler.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path coordinate (aux) foreach \X in {1,...,10}
  {node[anchor=west,minimum size=1.6em,draw,
  label={[name=l-\X,inner sep=0.25pt]center:{$\X$}}] 
  (aux) at (aux.east){}}
  foreach \X in {3,4}
  {(l-\X) edge[semithick,-stealth] (l-\the\numexpr\X+1)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `matrix` version:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    numbersrow/.style={
        matrix,
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            minimum size=1.6em,
            anchor=center,
            draw,
            node contents=\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[numbersrow](a){&&&&&&&&&\\};
\draw[->, shorten > =5pt, shorten <=5pt] (a-1-3.center)--(a-1-4.center);
\draw[->, shorten > =5pt, shorten <=5pt] (a-1-4.center)--(a-1-5.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]